# Creating a large amount of density lines in one plot

Tags: r, density-plot

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
DF<-as.data.frame(t(replicate(150, sample(seq(100, 1000),15,replace=T))),rownames=T)
```

I want to plot individual rows as densities so that I get a plot with multiple density curves. I know I can do it line by line like below:

```
plot(density(DF[,1]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,2]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,3]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,4]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,5]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,6]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,7]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,8]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,9]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,10]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,11]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,12]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
lines(density(DF[,13]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
#...and so forth
```

But I was wondering if there is an automated way to do all rows at once, otherwise the process becomes cumbersome very quickly.

Comment: Do you have a need for discerning the curves from each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop.

```
DF<-as.data.frame(t(replicate(150, sample(seq(100, 1000),15,replace=T))),rownames=T)
plot(density(DF[,1]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))
for (i in 2:ncol(DF)){
  lines(density(DF[, i]), col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = 0.5))
}
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: magnificient, this is what I needed

Answer (score 8):

You may also use lapply:

```
plot(density(DF[,1]),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5),ylim=c(0,0.0015))
lapply(DF[,-1],function(x){lines(density(x),col = adjustcolor('black', alpha.f = .5))}
)
```

[image]
If you wanted to use colours, you could consider something like this:

```
#making a palette
mycols <- rainbow(ncol(DF))

#plotting, now using numerical column indices to access colour at same time
plot(density(DF[,1]),col = adjustcolor(mycols[1], alpha.f = .5),ylim=c(0,0.0015))
lapply(2:ncol(DF),function(x){lines(density(DF[,x]),col = adjustcolor(mycols[x], alpha.f = .5))}
)
#add legend
legend(x=1100, y=0.0015,col=mycols,lty=1,legend=colnames(DF))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using `stack` and `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

head(stack(DF))
#   values ind
# 1    763  V1
# 2    833  V1
# 3    620  V1
# 4    819  V1
# 5    148  V1
# 6    549  V1

ggplot(stack(DF)) +
  geom_density(aes(x = values, color = ind))
```

[image: Plot 01]

If the densities are close enough to each other and you require "tails", you can probably get away with the following:

```
l <- density(DF$V1)

ggplot(stack(DF)) +
  geom_density(aes(x = values, color = ind)) +
  xlim(range(l$x))
```

[image: Plot with tails]